# UIResponder vs UIGestureRecognizer for Touch Event Response

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, uigesturerecognizer, uiresponder

I've been researching the various metods to program responses to touch events for an app that I'm building, and I'm a little confused by what I'm reading.

As far as I can tell, there are two generally accepted methods for responding to touch in iOS: gesture recognition and touch recognition.

When is it appropriate to use one or the other?

Specifically for what I'm building*:

I'm writing a controller for a view that needs to place items (UIImageViews) on screen where the user touches and also move them around as the user drags.  The controller is communicating with a separate model and so I need granular control of when to send messages to the model during touch events.

The model needs to know where the user first touches the screen (multitouch not enabled) and where the user lifts off the screen.  I need to query the model when the user first touches in order to find out if the user means to edit the location of an imageview or to create a new one, and I need to message the model about where the user lifts off the screen so that the model can be updated.  During a drag event also, I need to send constant queries to the model to determine if the location where the user is hovering at any given moment is valid.

At first I thought I could use a pan gesture recognizer to get the job done, but as I looked further into it, I couldn't figure out a way to set up custom function calls at touch-down, drag, and lift-off events (if there is a way, it'd be nice to know).  I found the UIResponder methods but are those still meant to be used, or is it best to work with just gesture recognizers in iOS6?

* code is not included because the scope of this question is fairly large and I don't want to distract people with needless detail.

Answer (score 1):

I came here because I was researching the efficiency of `UIGestureRecognizer` compared to the `UIResponder`-based touch event methods as I'm using them for a low latency application. For general use I can confirm that you can either override the `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended/Cancelled` etc methods in your `UIView` subclass or in a `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass (which is added to the `UIView`) or even in a `UIViewController` subclass (it's part of the Responder Chain like `UIView`).

You can also subclass a specific `UIGestureRecognizer` like Pan GR and override these methods to tack on additional functionality while leveraging what they already detect.  Be sure to call `super` (in all the cases above actually) and you'll probably want to check or updates the `state` property.

As for *my* question about which is more efficient, I don't know yet, but I'd imagine it's nearly equivalent.